# Why is my CSS grid creating four columns instead of one?

Tags: css

My standard page works exactly as I want it to. I want to create a single column when the screen width is less than 813px, but instead it changes to four cols. I've been reading a ton of posts and scratching my head for a couple hours now.

```
#page-container {
    position:relative;
    min-height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas:
        "header header"
        "comp-desc comp-desc"
        "profile-one desc-one"
        "desc-two profile-two"
        "footer footer";

    justify-content: space-between;
    justify-content: space-around;
    justify-content: center;
    grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    #page-container {
        min-height:100vh;
        width:100%;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "comp-desc"
            "profile-one"
            "desc-one"
            "profile-two"
            "desc-two"
            "footer";

        justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-around;
        justify-content: center;
        grid-row-gap: 2rem;
    }
}

#profile-one {
    grid-area: profile-one;
    grid-column: 1;
}

#one-desc {
    grid-area: desc-one;
    grid-column: 2/5;
}

#profile-two {
    grid-area: profile-two;
    grid-column: 2/5;
    margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

#two-desc {
    grid-area: desc-two;
    grid-column: 1;
}
```

Images here -
https://ibb.co/Pc7CvMQ
https://ibb.co/1mgZGJh

Code - https://codepen.io/CSJC/pen/XWmQPYa

Am I missing something obvious? I'm still learning so it's probably a simple mistake.

Comment: Can you please post your HTML code as well? It would be even nicer if you post your code in HTML/CSS code snippets.

Comment: Added a codepen and images. The first image is the page working as intended (minus private images). Its uses 2 columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will follow MOBILE FIRST APPROACH, then it will be very easy for you,

I would suggest you to create this on mobile first and then apply design for desktop in media query using `@media(min-width: 812px)`, min width selector in Media query will run if the screen is bigger than 812, or you can use display block in your current media query like this,

```css
 body{
 font-family:'Sen', sans-serif;
 transition:transform .2s;
 background-color:#171d22;
 min-height: 100vh;
}

a:focus {
 outline:none;
}

button:focus {
 outline:none;
}

h4 {
 color:white;
}

header {
 grid-area: header;
 grid-area: header;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
}

#page-container {
 position:relative;
 min-height: 100vh;
 width: 100%;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr;
 grid-template-areas:
  "header header"
  "comp-desc comp-desc"
  "profile-one desc-one"
  "desc-two profile-two"
  "footer footer";
 justify-content: space-between;
 justify-content: space-around;
 justify-content: center;
 grid-row-gap: 2rem;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
 #page-container {
  min-height:100vh;
  width:100%;
  display:block;
  grid-template-columns:1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
   "header"
   "comp-desc"
   "profile-one"
   "desc-one"
   "profile-two"
   "desc-two"
   "footer";

  justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-around;
  justify-content: center;
  grid-row-gap: 2rem;
 }
}

.navbar.navbar-expand-lg.navbar-light {
 /*position:fixed;*/
 width:100%;
 min-height:10vh;
 background-color:white;
 border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}

#logo {
 height:8vh;
 width:auto;
}

#nav-item:active {
 outline:0;
 border:none;
}

#nav-link:active {
 outline:0;
 border:none;
}

.dropdown-item:hover {
 background-color: #f8f9fa;
}

#head {
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#171d22;
 color:white;
 padding:10vh 0px 0px 0px;
 margin-bottom:2rem;
}

.comp-desc {
 margin-top: 10vh;
 grid-area: comp-desc;
 text-align:center;
 background-color:#171d22;
 color:white;
 font-size:1.25rem;
 margin:2rem 2.5% 3rem 2.5%;
}

.comp-desc p {
 padding:0.5rem 0px;
}

.profile {
 margin:5%;
 display:grid;
 background-color:#171d22;
 color:white;
 justify-content:center;
 justify-content:space-between;
 justify-content:space-around;
 align-items:center;
 margin-bottom:1.5rem;
}

#profile-one {
 grid-area: profile-one;
 grid-column: 1;
}

#one-desc {
 grid-area: desc-one;
 grid-column: 2/5;
}

#profile-two {
 grid-area: profile-two;
 grid-column: 2/5;
 margin-bottom: 3rem;
}

#two-desc {
 grid-area: desc-two;
 grid-column: 1;
}

.description {
 text-align:center;
 align-self:center;
 font-size:1.25rem;
 color:white;
 overflow:auto;
 margin:0px 5%;
 padding: 2rem 3rem;
}

#profile-img-boundaries{
 overflow:hidden;
}

#profile-img-F {
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 object-fit:contain;
 overflow:hidden;
 align-self:center;
}

#profile-img-M {
 width: 100%;
 height:auto;
 object-fit:contain;
 border-width:auto;
 overflow:hidden;
}

.profile-desc {
 overflow:hidden;
 margin: 5%;
}

.headers {
 text-align:center;
 display:flex;
 flex-direction:column;
 justify-content:center;
 align-content:center;
 align-items:center;
 padding-top:10px;
}

.headers:hover {
 background-color: #000000;
}

.nametag {
 color:white;
 width:33%;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}

.btn.btn-dark {
 background-color:#171d22;
}

.modal-button {
 border:none;
 padding:0px;
 margin:0px;
}

.modal-footer {
 display:grid;
 grid-template-columns:1fr 1fr; 
}

.modal-link {
 color:rgb(244,212,69);
}

.modal-link img {
 height:100px;
 width:45%;
}

#footer {
 grid-area: footer;

 background-color:#ffffff;
 left:0;
 bottom:0;
 width:100%;
 min-height:10vh;
 color:#171d22;
 text-align:center;
 display:inline-flex;
 flex-direction:row;
 align-items:center;
 justify-content:center;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.foot-img {
 width:auto;
 height:8vh;
 display:flex;
 justify-content:space-between;
}

.foot-img:hover{
 transform:scale(1.1);
}

#spacer {
 /*keep for spacing*/
 height:8vh;
 width:auto;
}

#links {
 /*keep for spacing*/
}

#license-logo {
 height:8vh;
 width:auto;
 /* create right margin as vh for equidistance*/
 margin-right:2vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="page-container">
        <header>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
                <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
                    <span class="w-100 d-lg-none d-block">
                        <!-- hidden spacer to center brand on mobile --></span>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                        <img src="images/logo_blackWhite.png" id="logo">
                    </a>
                    <div class="w-100 text-right">
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-1 text-right" id="myNavbar">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto flex-nowrap">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="index.html" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                <span class="dropdown-item">Home</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="portfolio.html" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                <span class="dropdown-item">Portfolio</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="contact.html" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="true">
                                <span class="dropdown-item">Contact</span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="comp-desc">
            <h1 id="head">Meet the people behind anonymous anonymous</h1>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum.
            </p>
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum.
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-desc profile" id="profile-one" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#about_anonymous" class="modal-button">
            <div id="profile-img-boundaries">
                <img src="images/anonymous.jpg" id="profile-img-F">
            </div>
            <div class="headers">
                <h3 class="nametag">
                    anonymous
                </h3>
                <h4>
                    Graphic Design & Video
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="about_anonymous" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="about_anonymous" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" id="about_anonymous" style="color:rgb(244,212,69);">
                                Contact anonymous
                            </h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/anonymousanonymousanonymous" target="_blank">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark modal-link">
                                    <img src="images/li_white.png">
                                </button>
                            </a>
                            <a href="https://twitter.com/anonymousanonymous23" target="_blank">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark modal-link">
                                    <img src="images/tw_white.png">
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- end modal -->
        </div>
        <div class="description" id="one-desc">
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="profile-desc profile" id="profile-two" type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#about_anonymous" class="modal-button">
            <div id="profile-img-boundaries">
                <img src="images/anonymous.jpg" id="profile-img-M">
            </div>
            <div class="headers">
                <h3 class="nametag">
                    anonymous
                </h3>
                <h4>
                    Graphic Design & Illustration
                </h4>
            </div>
            <!-- Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" id="about_anonymous" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="about_anonymous" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h5 class="modal-title" style="color: rgb(244,212,69);">
                                Contact anonymous
                            </h5>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark modal-link">
                                    <img src="images/li_white.png">
                                </button>
                            </a>
                            <a href="#" target="_blank">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-dark modal-link">
                                    <img src="images/tw_white.png">
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- End modal -->
        </div>
        <div class="description" id="two-desc">
            <p>Lorem ipsum.</p>
        </div>
        <footer id="footer">
            <!-- spacer -->
            <img src="images/logo_spacer.png" id="license-logo">
            <div id="links">
                <!-- Linkedin -->
                <a href="https://uk.linkedin.com/in/anonymousanonymousanonymous" target="_blank"><img src="images/li.png" class="foot-img"></a>
                <!-- Twitter -->
                <a href="https://twitter.com/anonymousanonymous23" target="_blank"><img src="images/tw.png" class="foot-img"></a>
                <!-- Insta -->
                <a href="https://www.instagram.com/anonymous" target="_blank"><img src="images/ig.png" class="foot-img"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo_blackWhite.png" id="license-logo">
            </a>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

and also don't use your scripts in Header or start of the body, this is a bad practice and will hamper the page performance, use all your scripts in bottom of the body.

Comment: I generally don't leave my scripts at the top, I just never got around to moving them! Thanks for your answer.

Comment: okay, And as you can see how I use position stickey for your header, this would also help you to make it better

Answer (score 1):

Unset the grid-column for `#one-desc` and `#profile-two`, then it will shows 1 column for device screen width below 812px. Please make sure the media query settings are placed after the general CSS selectors settings.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 812px) {
    #page-container {
        min-height:100vh;
        width:100%;
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:1fr;
        grid-template-areas:
            "header"
            "comp-desc"
            "profile-one"
            "desc-one"
            "profile-two"
            "desc-two"
            "footer";

        justify-content: space-between;
        justify-content: space-around;
        justify-content: center;
        grid-row-gap: 2rem;
    }

  #one-desc {
    grid-column: unset; /* Unset the grid column */
  }

  #profile-two {
    grid-column: unset; /* unset the grid column */
  }
}
```